# Organisational chart class in PHP

Tags: php

Does anyone know where I could find a PHP class to generate organizational charts?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying Graphviz (http://www.graphviz.org/).
It isn't written in pure php, but it is easily callable from a script using the exec() function.
It is quite easy to use but very powerful and customizable, and it is also the backend used by Doxygen to generate class documentation charts..

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [cogmap](http://www.cogmap.com), they have an [api](http://www.cogmap.com/blog/2008/03/04/cogmap-apis/) you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google chart tools

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart

Answer (score -2):

You can try XML Charts:
http://www.maani.us/xml_charts/index.php

Or Pchart:
http://pchart.sourceforge.net/